# How to wait for reindexing in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `ElasticSearch` with index `posts` setted up. I'm pushing new documents to it from time to time.

I want `ElasticSearch` to reply to my queries only when all documents are indexed. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it the same program that pushes documents and sends search queries? If yes, you can control that on the client side, right?

Comment: @Val yeah, I can. But how can I know does elastic search indexed or no?

Comment: In ES2 you can't but in ES5 you will be able to send your index queries with [`?refresh=wait_for`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-refresh.html) and ES will only respond when the new documents are ready to be searched.

Comment: Hm, thanks! Is there any way to solve this problem in the 2.x without synthetic `sleep(time)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ES 2, you can call the [`refresh` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) just after having indexed your new documents, but it's not advised to do it in production as it may decrease the performance of your cluster.

In ES5, you will be able to send your index queries with [`?refresh=wait_for`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-refresh.html) and ES will only respond when the new documents are ready to be searched.

Comment: Can't get `ES2` approach, even on their documentation. You mean, `ES` wouldn't response to my queries until it reindex everything, if I called refresh, right?

Comment: No, you simply need to do it all synchronously, first index, then call refresh, then send your queries

Comment: you mean `refresh` response only when reindexing finishes?

Comment: When you make your indexing calls (bulk or otherwise), as soon as they finish, you can call `refresh` and then your queries are guaranteed to take the new documents into account.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. Let me test today and give you an answer, please