# Calling Search immediately after indexing fails intermittently in Elasticsearch NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am using `NEST` `Elasticsearch` client and trying to do Unit test. I see that GET starts working immediately but SEARCH takes few milliseconds, causing the Tests to fail intermittently.

```
await _elasticClient.GetAsync<User>(id)).Source; //Works fine 
elasticClient.Search<User>(s =>
                s.Query(q =>
                    q.MultiMatch(x =>
                        x.Fields(f => f
                            .Field(petType => petType.Name, 3)
                            .Field(petType => petType.Category)
                    )));
             // response.Documents is empty many times.
```

Adding a delay of 500ms between Index and Search statements works but makes the tests slow.

Is there a way to solve this.

I believe search follows eventual consistency. I am going to attempt to configure number of replicas or shards to 1 to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by calling Refresh API.

```
await _client.Indices.RefreshAsync("index-name");
```

Refresh waits for the Indexing to complete.
This answer can be referred.

[How to wait for reindexing in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38864048/3613702)